# Using Ubuntu One cloud services on a Nokia E7

Tags: 10.04, ubuntu-one, cloud

is there a http:\ address for mapping Ubuntu One cloud services on my Nokia E7 by using remote drives, I have done so for mapping 4Shared, and Dropbox can be done via a WebDav application, is there anyway of doing it for free like 4Shared instead of paying a premium for a webdav subscription?
ThankYou

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no API like this for Ubuntu One. There is a REST API, but no WebDav.

It has already been requested in a [feature request](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/396725), but currently it isn't in the to-do list. Sorry.